# Can I optimize such a MySQL query without using an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

A simplified version of my MySQL db looks like this:

```
Table books (ENGINE=MyISAM)
id <- KEY
publisher <- LONGTEXT
publisher_id <- INT <- This is a new field that is currently null for all records

Table publishers (ENGINE=MyISAM)
id <- KEY
name <- LONGTEXT
```

Currently books.publisher holds values that keep getting repeated, but that the publishers.name holds uniquely.
I want to get rid of books.publisher and instead populate the books.publisher_id field.

The straightforward SQL code that describes what I want done, is as follows:

```
UPDATE books 
JOIN publishers ON books.publisher = publishers.name 
SET books.publisher_id = publishers.id;
```

The problem is that I have a big number of records, and even though it works, it's taking forever.

Is there a faster solution than using something like this in advance?:

```
CREATE INDEX publisher ON books (publisher(20));
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I thought you were trying to do

SET books.publisher_id = publishers.id; No?

Comment: Can you clarify "big number of records?" What access method (InnoDB? MyISAM?) are you using? By "forever," I presume you mean it hasn't yet completed.  This kind of stuff takes a long time. This kind of one-time reorganization of data can take multiple hours to complete, and sometimes needs to run overnight or some such.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:php] right?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @MalcolmDiggs, I fixed it on the question.

Comment: To answer your question @OllieJones, it's a few thousand records and this is not a one-off query, I will have to run it weekly for a few months while another physical transition is taking place.

And sorry for the misunderstanding, when I say forever it doesn't mean it never ends. It ends, it's just taking a little too long for me to think that it can't get optimized.

Comment: @geomagas nothing other than I run it via PHP code.

Comment: @PhotoPaul: Which is irrelevant to the issue, _and so is the tag_.

Comment: True, I just removed the php tag. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here that might be helped by optimization.

First of all, a few thousand rows doesn't count as "big" ... that's "medium."

Second, in MySQL saying "I want to do this without indexes" is like saying "I want to drive my car to New York City, but my tires are flat and I don't want to pump them up. What's the best route to New York if I'm driving on my rims?"

Third, you're using a `LONGTEXT` item for your publisher.  Is there some reason not to use a fully indexable datatype like `VARCHAR(200)`?  If you do that your WHERE statement will run faster, index or none. Large scale library catalog systems limit the length of the publisher field, so your system can too.

Fourth, from one of your comments this looks like a routine data maintenance update, not a one time conversion.  So you need to figure out how to avoid repeating the whole deal over and over. I am guessing here, but it looks like newly inserted rows in your `books` table have a publisher_id of zero, and your query updates that column to a valid value.

So here's what to do.  First, put an index on tables.publisher_id.

Second, run this variant of your maintenance query:

```
UPDATE books 
  JOIN publishers ON books.publisher = publishers.name 
   SET books.publisher_id = publishers.id
 WHERE books.publisher_id = 0
 LIMIT 100;
```

This will limit your update to rows that haven't yet been updated. It will also update 100 rows at a time. In your weekly data-maintenance job, re-issue this query until MySQL announces that your query affected zero rows (look at mysqli::rows_affected or the equivalent in your php-to-mysql interface). That's a great way to monitor database update progress and keep your update operations from getting out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title says ".. optimize ... query without using an index?"

What have you got against using an index?

You should always examine the execution plan if a query is running slowly. I would guess it's having to scan the `publishers` table for each row in order to find a match. It would make sense to have an index on `publishers.name` to speed the lookup of an `id`.

You can drop the index later but it wouldn't harm to leave it in, since you say the process will have to run for a while until other changes are made. I imagine the `publishers` table doesn't get update very frequently so performance of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on the table should not be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your update query has invalid syntax but you can fix that later.  The way to get it to run faster is to add a where clause so that you are only updating the necessary records.

Comment: I don't think a `WHERE` clause is going to help, he's updating a new field added to the table, so _all_ rows will be changed.

Comment: Although, to be fair, the addition of a `WHERE` clause would be good to speed up subsequent updates.

Comment: Subsequent updates was what I had in mind also.  If the first one takes a long time, it's not that big a deal because you only have to do it once.